# Is it possible to set a gradient box-shadow to div that has a background-image?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has an image as a background-image, I need to set a linear gradient box-shadow but it can't get two background-image.
I need something like the below image
[image]

my Html code is:

```
<div class="top-container"></div>
```

css:

```
 .top-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 632px;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/homepage-images/header-desk-bg-img.jpg");

  }
```

I need just gradient shadow from top to bottom of the below image

Comment: First of all you missing **"(double quotes)** in `<div class="top-container></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding `box-shadow` property.

I do not know what values you should give to it, but this is an excellent tool where you can play with `box-shadow` values to set it up the way you like the most.
https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

So, by the end of your trying you will end up with something like this:

```
 .top-container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 632px;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/homepage-images/header-desk-bg-img.jpg");
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  }
```

Comment: but it's not gradient, I know that I can set box-shadow but I need gradient box-shadow

Comment: You can set box shadow to be like it is gradient. Did you check css matic site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) if you want to apply a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

```css
.top-container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: cyan;
}

.top-container::after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, transparent);;
}
```

```html
<div class='top-container'></div>
```

The [CSS property `box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) can also do the work.

```css
.top-container{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: cyan;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='top-container'></div>
```

Comment: but it's not gradient, I know that I can set box-shadow but I need gradient box-shadow

Comment: use ::after to do it, I'm gonna edit my post to show you a piece of code